# NullPointerException while trying to use mock for verifying the use of a method

Tags: java, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, mockito

I'm using mockito to test the next method.

```java
protected void mapSubEntitiesSourceColToSubEntitiesTargetCol(Source source, Target target) throws
    MapperCreationException, MappingException {
    Mapper<SourceSubEntity, TargetSubEntity> subEntitiesSourceColToSubEntitiesTargetColMapper = mapperFactory.createMapper(SourceSubEntity.class, TargetSubEntity.class);
    Collection<TargetSubEntity> mappedValue = new LinkedList<>();
    for (SourceSubEntity e : source.getSubEntitiesSourceCol()) {
        mappedValue.add(subEntitiesSourceColToSubEntitiesTargetColMapper.apply(e));
    }
    target.setSubEntitiesTargetCol(mappedValue);
}
```

and here is my test:

```java
@Test
public void TestMappingSubEntitiesSourceColToSubEntitiesTargetCol() throws 
MapperCreationException, MappingException {
    Source mockedSource = Mockito.mock(Source.class);
    Target mockedTarget = Mockito.mock(Target.class);
    SourceSubEntity sourceSubEntity = Mockito.mock(SourceSubEntity.class);
    TargetSubEntity targetSubEntity = Mockito.mock(TargetSubEntity.class);
    MapperFactory mapperFactory = Mockito.mock(MapperFactory.class);
    Mapper<SourceSubEntity, TargetSubEntity> subEntitiesSourceColToSubEntitiesTargetColMapper = mapperFactory.createMapper(SourceSubEntity.class, TargetSubEntity.class);

    Collection<SourceSubEntity> subEntitiesSourceCol = Arrays.asList(sourceSubEntity, sourceSubEntity);

    SourceToTargetMapper sttm = new SourceToTargetMapper(targetModelObjectFactory,mappingOperatorFactory,mapperFactory,valueProducerFactory);
    Mockito.when(mockedSource.getSubEntitiesSourceCol()).thenReturn(subEntitiesSourceCol);
    Mockito.when(subEntitiesSourceColToSubEntitiesTargetColMapper.apply(sourceSubEntity)).thenReturn((TargetSubEntity) Arrays.asList(targetSubEntity));

    sttm.mapSubEntitiesSourceColToSubEntitiesTargetCol(mockedSource,mockedTarget);
    Mockito.verify(mockedTarget, Mockito.times(1)).setSubEntitiesTargetCol(Mockito.any());
```

The problem that I'm facing here is that I get a `NullPointerException` for `subEntitiesSourceColToSubEntitiesTargetColMapper.apply(e)`.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: In your test, the line "Mapper<SourceSubEntity, TargetSubEntity> subEntitiesSourceColToSubEntitiesTargetColMapper = mapperFactory.createMapper(SourceSubEntity.class, TargetSubEntity.class);" returned null. I believe what you meant is Mapper<SourceSubEntity, TargetSubEntity> subEntitiesSourceColToSubEntitiesTargetColMapper = Mockito.mock(Mapper.class); and then Mockito.when(mapperFactory.createMapper(SourceSubEntity.class, TargetSubEntity.class)).thenReturn(subEntitiesSourceColToSubEntitiesTargetColMapper);

Comment: @Jayr yes!! That was my problem! thank you! Could you please explain to me why this is the right approach?

Comment: Since mapperFactory is a mocked instance, any calls to its functions are to return null until you instruct them what to return.